# AxWindowsMediaPlayer Compatibility

Tags: vb.net, windows-media-player

I have a project to create a form with windows media player for playing mp4 video. 
The form contains a groupbox which has wmp and some other controls. The groupbox is invisible until users want to play videos. 
My program work fine on my computer, and I also try it on several different computer with different OS such as win-xp, win7, and win10. It's all work.

In case of some old computers, I use .NET Framework 2.0 for this project.
Everything looks good...

However, when I demo to my customers, the groupbox and other controls worked fine, but the wmp didn't show up. But I still can hear the sound from video.
I've tried 3 computers on my customer's site. One worked normally and the other two only had sound but no video.

No video means that nothing shows up, even the black screen. I only can see my form with a empty space.

I think the problem results from the environment, but I have no clue to fix this issue. Could some body give me a hand or hint or keyword?

Comment: First thing you would be interested in checking is whether standalone WMP plays the file there. Also OS is stiĺl important.

Comment: Yes, I've checked that. The files can be played in every computer with standalone WMP.

Comment: Also it should be standalone and in the same time the same bitness as your app. Even though it looks the same for interactive user, WMP handles MP4 files differently in different OS versions, and in certain cases even differently in 32/64 bit versions on the same system. The symptom of playing audio only suggests you're having the issue on an old Windows system and the environment in your app is not handling H.264 video correctly, which is a typical problem.